# Convergence almost sure pointless?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

A very common type of convergence in probability theory is 'almost sure convergence'. I don't understand why this type is used at all. In principle, we should always be able to substitute it by a uniform convergence almost sure due to Egorov's theorem. So why do people in probability theory refer to this weaker concept?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Uniform convergence except on a null set does not hold, only uniform convergence except on some set of measure less than epsilon, for every positive epsilon. // About your question itself, almost sure convergence is pointwise convergence for equivalence classes of random variables, that is, when one identifies random variables that are equal except on a null set (and this quotient space of functions is the relevant one in most parts of probability theory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is useful to operate with a *pair* of concepts, such as a.e. convergence and almost uniform convergence, of which one is visibly weaker but in fact implies the other.  When you **use** this property, you can use the stronger one. When you have to **prove that it holds**, you  will want to prove the weaker one.

Given a sequence $X_n$, would you rather prove that they converge a.e., or that they converge almost uniformly.  For a.e., the proof naturally begins with

> Suppose $X_n$ fail to converge a.e.  Then there exists a set $E$ of positive measure on which convergence fails everywhere. From this set we select a subset  such that ... ...  and arrive at a contradiction.

Having this concrete set $E$ on which things go badly focuses the effort in the above proof.

For almost uniform convergence, what would you do?

> Suppose $X_n$ fail to converge almost uniformly.  Then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for every set $E$ with $P(E)<\epsilon$ the sequence fails to converge uniformly on the complement of $E$. Hmm....

You don't get much to work with here.